# visio strangeness modifying shapesheet

Tags: microsoft-visio-2016

I am trying to make a slight modification to Visio's Bent Arrow shapesheet. I want it to not draw the small line at the opposite end of the arrow. I opened the shapesheet, found the "LineTo" geometry that I wanted to remove, and changed this to "MoveTo." At first, this appeared to work. However, when I changed the height of the shape, the arc acted wonky.

Assuming I screwed something up, I went back in and changed the line back to "LineTo", however, the wonky arc behavior did not go away. I am 100% confident that this was the only change I made to the shapesheet, and I tested this a few times.

Any ideas why this is messing up the arc?

[image]

Comment: Could you be more specific about which stencil this shape is from?

Comment: It's from the "Arrow Shapes" stencil, labeled as "Bent Arrow". I did "move" the control for the arrow head to make the arrow head disappear.

Comment: Ah, that shape is not in earlier versions of Visio, at least, not in Visio 2010. Perhaps it is Visio-2016 specific. I shall undo my edit of the tags.

Comment: Now I have access to Visio 2016, I have now tried it and it all seems to work ok. Maybe there has been an update that has fixed something. It's the 2nd line in the geometry section that you need to change.